# How to split an array into 2, left and right

Tags: javascript

I have an array of menu links `['A','B','C','D','X','Y','Z']` and I want to split them into an array with this result  `{'left':['A','B','C','D'], 'right': ['X', 'Y','Z']}`.  I want them split in half.  The number of items in the list can variable. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to extract subarrays from an array:

```js
var arr = ['A','B','C','D','X','Y','Z'],
    mid = Math.ceil(arr.length/2),
    obj = {
        left: arr.slice(0, mid),
        right: arr.slice(mid)
    };
```

If you don't mind altering the original array, you can also use [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
var arr = ['A','B','C','D','X','Y','Z'],
    obj = {
        left: arr.splice(0, Math.ceil(arr.length/2)),
        right: arr
    };
```

Answer (score 5):

Split array into two parts with `slice` function.

```
var numbers= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    leftEnd= Math.ceil(numbers.length/2),
    result= {
        left: numbers.slice(0,leftEnd),
        right: numbers.slice(leftEnd)
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function splitInTwo(arr){
    var middle = Math.ceil(arr.length / 2);
    return {
        left: test.slice( 0, middle ),
        right: test.slice( middle )
    };
}

var test = ['A','B','C','D','X','Y','Z'];

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify( splitInTwo(test) );
```